# How to restrict user to select date between range of years in django?

Tags: python, django, model, datefield

**models.py**

```
class Completion(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
```

In above code `DateField()` generates a date selecting widget in admin site where you can select proper date or enter it manually in a textbox. The problems are:

1. How do I restrict the user to select a Date that comes under year 2000 to 2100.
2. when user manually types a date in the text-box, it accepts any date that's in format yy-mm-dd. I need validation so non existing date should not be entered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [validators](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/)!

First, define your validator:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_current_century(value):
    if value < 2000 or value > 2100:
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not a valid year!' % value)
```

Now you can use it in your model field:

```
class Completion(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(validators=[validate_current_century])
    end_date = models.DateField(validators=[validate_current_century])
```

And also in a form field:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    current_century_field = forms.DateField(validators=[validate_current_century])
```

More details in the docs, linked to above.

Comment: Thanks Ori for the answer.I got it almost correct but when raise ValidationError comes to execution i got an error : 

global name 'ValidationError' is not defined

Comment: @anks, did you forget the import statement? Also, are you using Django 1.2 or greater?